# How to write mapbox expression for inputting multiple columns, comparing their values and triggering filter within the map?

Tags: javascript, mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

Here is my expression for single column value filtration. This is fine for one column(Project_Name) but I need to input multiple columns:

```
var expression = [
                    "any",
                        ["in", ["get", "Project_Name"], ["literal", [selected.innerHTML]]
                      ]];
```

Tried Approaches:

#1:

```
   var features = map.queryRenderedFeatures(e.point);
                      
   var long = String(features[0].properties.Longitude);
   var lat = String(features[0].properties.Latitude);  
                      
   var expression1 = [
                        "any",
                        ['in', long, ['get', 'Longitude']],
                        ['in', lat, ['get', 'Latitude']],
                        ["in", ["get", "Project_Name"], ["literal",[selected.innerHTML]]
                      ]];
```

#2:

```
 var expression2 = ['match', 
                      ['in', long, ['get', 'Longitude']],
                      ['in', lat, ['get', 'Latitude']]
                    ];
```

This doesn't result in any error but it doesn't give the desired filtered results. If somebody knows how to figure this out, your help is very much valuable.

I believe following images will give perfect illustration of what I mean:

Before filtering the map:[image]

1. When I click on symbol, the results that I want:[image]
2. The results that I get:[image]

So basically what I am trying to achieve is that, all my symbols should be filtered out strictly on the basis of coordinates and not on the basis of project names.

If this post requires to be edited with more information, don't hesitate to ask. Feel free. Thanks.

Comment: Can you please provide what results are being returned?

Comment: @Keimeno, I can't provide actual results for my query because the map filtered is of 300+ symbols which are filtered.

However I'll illustrate a scenario to you. The Project_Name 'Amazon Pittsburgh' has two project statuses: 1. Active 2. Awarded & Won.

So basically I want to get the one with only 'Active' status. My approach to this was filtering out the whole map with symbols matching latitude and longitude, so how can I pass values of two columns simultaneously as an expression that filters out the map with only the symbols that are required.

Answer (score 0):

Your approach is correct: using the `['any']` operator to combine multiple expressions as an OR.

If this is not working, your problem is with the individual expressions.

For starters, your second expression is trying to match the value of the field `Longitude` within the string `90.18`. That seems unlikely to be what you want. Maybe you want to compare with a number: `['==', ['get', 'Longitude'], 90.18]`

Also you have inconsistent case: `Longitude`, `latitude`.

It's not really clear what you're trying to achieve, though.

Comment: Although I think that using ['match'] operator to combine multiple expressions as an AND would fit the requirement if I am not mistaken(came up after sometime in the second approach but even that isn't working).

Comment: Hey Steve, I've updated the question for better interpretation of my query. If you feel you need more info, just tell so.